# Java Base64 Sun to JDK8

Tags: java, encoding, java-8, base64, sun

I have a bunch of strings in the DB which were encoded with the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` a while ago.

Now I wanna decode (and encode further strings) with `java.util.Base64`.

The difference between these two is that the Sun one added a new line string at each n characters

**Example:**

```
Sun Base64:   54y49568uyj304j534w5y
              34y0639j6yh93j5h0653j
              s45hr68o

JDK8 Base64:  54y49568uyj304j534w5y34y0639j6yh93j5h0653js45hr68o
```

In order for the JDK decoder to parse these zipped strings, I would need to remove the new line characters.

**Questions:**

1. Do I remove `\r\n` (Unix) or `\n` (Windows) or `\r` (old Macs)? Because the strings depend on which machine they were encoded
2. If I say `zippedString.replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", "")` how can I make sure that I won't have a `\r` chacter in the actual string, resulting in corrupted data?
3. Is there any other way to create a bridge between these two mechanisms?

Comment: There is no `\r\n` in a base 64 encoded string so you can probably remove them (it depends on the encoding process, for instance, one might encode word by word or line by line), see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-4

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64: no `\r` or `\n`

Comment: Have you tried using the Java 8 mime decoder? It is documented to ignore newlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no white space in Base64 so I would remove the all.

```
String toDecode = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

This removes any ambiguity on how to handle specific newlines or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**The purpose of ‘\r’ and ‘\n’ characters here is purely related to text formatting and you can assume they’re invisible.**

The code that reads the string value should take care of filtering them out, whatever method is used e.g.

read line -> trim -> concatenate

Then, decode the concatenated string.

*As a digression, suppose a different encoding algorithm was applied with these characters being part of the encoding alphabet. Because Java interprets ‘\r’ and ‘\n’ characters as an indicator of a new line (depending on the operating system), the string representation of the encoded value would need to be escaped, e.g “14y6\\n75b….”. **However, this would’ve caused more problems than benefits hence should be avoided.***